# Which library in order to manipulate image with mouse in C

Tags: c, image, image-processing, gtk

I would like to know which libray offers the possiblity of manipulate object over an image with his mouse.

For example in Gimp, you can create a line in choosing the start point and the end point.

I heard about GooCanvas, but I'm not sure it is possible to do that with it.

I would like to know which librayr can I use to implement that in a gtk application in C?

Thanks

Comment: You don't do it in one step. You do it in two steps: 1. handle mouse events, 2. draw on screen. For Linux, the first can be achieved using `libxdo`, the second with ImageMagick, maybe some components of GTK+ or Qt, etc...

Comment: You might consider using (in C++, not C) [Qt GraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/graphicsview.html)

Comment: Yes that what I want to do, but I have to do it in C please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use GTK3 with [cairo](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cairo-Interaction.html) (i.e. [cairographics](http://www.cairographics.org/)). e.g. [GtkDrawingArea](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.8/GtkDrawingArea.html). See [zetcode](http://zetcode.com) tutorials on [GTK](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/) & [cairo](http://zetcode.com/gfx/cairo/).

<sup>NB: *GooCanvas* is probably obsolete with GTK ***3***</sup>

GTK3 will be useful for mouse related things, and Cairo for drawing.

You could consider also [libSDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) instead.

Comment: He should give a look at [clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org).